# Content-based movie similarity metric

Tags: apache-spark, similarity, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I'm building a content-based recommendation system for movies.
The way I do it is I first convert movie information into Sparse Vectors. For info like genres, actors, producers, etc. I use binary representation - whether an item is present in a movie. For Title and Plot I compute TF-IDF and get a sparse vector of term weights.

After that I calculate the user profile by combining user ratings with movies vector profiles: summing up movies data-vectors with positive ratings and subtracting those with negative ratings.

Then the last step is to calculate the similarity between user-profile and all the other movies.

I separated all the feature vectors (separate vector for genres, separate for actors, title, etc.) so that I can adjust the weights which similarity matters more overall.

```
private val titleWeight = 0.5
private val plotWeight = 0.5
private val actorsWeight = 1
private val genresWeight = 0.8
private val directorsWeight = 0.3
private val writersWeight = 0.3
private val productionsWeight = 0.2
private val decadeWeight = 0.2
private val countriesWeight = 0.05
```

I've tried using cosine similarity to compare user profile with movie profiles. But there is a problem - plot and title similarities always produce very low values compared to other similarities even if user has actually rated movies with similar titles/plots.

This probably happens because the user profile plot vector, for example, will have very many values once user rates multiple movies. And cosine similarity is calculated by dividing dot product by the multiplied lengths of input vectors (if I'm doing it correctly). Or, basically, taking dot product of the normalised vectors.
Thus, say, profile plot vector will have 500 TF*IDF values - each value is somewhat between 1 and 10 in my case. And the intersection with the movie plot vector would probably happen in 5 places maximum typically (5 terms will co-occur in the current movie and in already rated movies). In common sense that seems like a big intersection. And such plots should be considered similar. But the cosine similarity will give a value, say, 0.02...

While genres/actors/productions, etc will produce much larger values in the case of intersections.

I tried adjusting the weights in various ways, I also tried using dot product instead of cosine similarity for title and plot. But that only produced worth results..

Now I'm thinking - what am I doing wrong. And how can I make Title and Plot similarities somewhere comparable to other similarities I have.

Sorry for the long text.